# Pass a hardcoded value in an open url action expression - SSRS

Tags: url, reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2012

I have a dashboard where I link KPIs to other reports that are just listings with more information.  I need to link a text box by using the open URL action but I can't seem to get the syntax in the action expression correct. I need this text box to pass the Forestry Unit value of 6 to the "Inspector_Listing_Borough" report.  This is what I currently have:

="javascript:void(window.open('http://forestryreports.parks.nycnet/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fReports%2fForMS_Prod%2fQA_Dashboard%2fInspector_Listing%2fInspector_Listing_Borough &ForestryUnit="&(Fields!ForestryUnit.Value,"6")&"&rs:Command=Render'))"

Comment: I use that link on our CRM;

="javascript:void(window.open('http://192.*************/CRM/main.asp&pagetype=entityrecord&id=" &Fields!ID.Value.ToString() & "','_blank'))"

Comment: Thanks Mahmut, where is the hardcoded value in this expression?